# C# - Find a cell through a textBox in dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, search, datagridview, textbox

I've already searched for some solutions to my problem, but still didn't find anything working for me. So I signed up to get some help for my problem. Appreciate help.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("FirstNames", "FirstName");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("SecondNames", "SecondName");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("AccountNames", "AccountName");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Emailaddresses", "Emailaddress");

    try
    {
        // enter AD settings  
        PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domaene"]));

        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(AD)))
        {
            foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
            {
                DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add
                (
                    de.Properties["givenName"].Value,
                    de.Properties["sn"].Value,
                    de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value,
                    de.Properties["userPrincipalname"].Value
                );                          
            }
        }
    }    
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

This is the way how I create my ActiveDirectory and put it into my dataGridView. The function I am searching for is how to search through this DVG with a textBox. So I already tried something like this:

```
String searchValue = textBox1.Text;
int rowIndex = -1;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[2].Value != null) // Need to check for null if new row is exposed
    {
        if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
        {
            rowIndex = row.Index;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This snippet is from another post of this site. I tried it on my build and it didn't work for me. It throws a System.NullReferenceException when I put something in my textBox. The problem: I really don't know why it doesn't work. 
Will appreciate any answer!

Greetings,
MarvinR

Comment: where does it thrown the exception exactly? which line?

Comment: if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))

Comment: Shouldn't this line checking for null `if (row.Cells[2].Value != null)` have `Cells[1]` instead? I'm assuming it gets to the new row and `Cells[1]` does not have a value and therefore cannot be cast to a string so it throws the error.

Comment: same error if i let it check foor == null. But now in the changed line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you would like to enumerate through all cells and once you find the value you are searching for to return the row index of this cell. Therefore your code should be as non-prompt to null reference exceptions as it could be. An example of such a method.

```
private int SearchValueRowIndex()
{
    string searchValue = textBox1.Text;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.Value != null && cell.Value.ToString() == searchValue)
            {
                return cell.RowIndex;
            }
        }
    }

    // Not found
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I get some errors with the 'return'. Don't really know how to implement these into my void. Guess I'm quite to nooby for this.

Comment: You can't return anything in a void. See the first line of this example, it returns an integer `private int SearchValueRowIndex()`.

Comment: In general there are two type of methods in C#. One that returns variable as the one above which returns variable of type Integer and one that does not return value or void method as your initial method. Depend on your scenario you can use either.

Comment: thatswhy I searched for a way to try your snippet in my code, but didn't find it.

Comment: You can easily modify the above method to be non-returnable. Just replace "int" with "void" keyword, initialize local variable "int rowIndex = -1" as you did before and finally replace the "return" keywords with "rowIndex =".

Comment: after an hour of testing I finally found a solution including your snippet. Its not really got but atleast working.. thanks for the help. Now I can find the row including the first name of a person in our active directory. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var dg = new DataGrid();
var tb = new TextBox();
tb.ID = "myTextBox"

foreach (DataGridItem item in dg.Items)
{
    foreach (var cell in item.Cells)
    {
        TextBox val = (TextBox)item.FindControl("textboxid here");
        if (val.Text == tb.Text)
        {
            //do something here
        }
    }
}
```

This will loop through each of the rows and the cellslooking for a value in a specific textbox, if you need to loop through other textboxes you could write another bit of code to look for all the controls in the data grid.

Comment: thanks for the answer - but which assembly's do I need to use 'ID' and 'Items' ? Sorry, bloody starter here.

Comment: you should be able to just drop this in to your code, just ignore the first 3 lines, and rename `dg.Items` to `dataGridView1.Items` everything else should work .  Are you getting compile errors

Comment: Yes, it tells me that there is no Definition for 'Items'. Even tells me that it could be possible that there are Assemby's missing. Still getting compile errors with <code>dataGridView1.Items</code>.

Answer (score 0):

As a addition to what ivayle said you can also select the whole row if you will use the whole row's data later in your program:

```
        string searchValue = textBox1.Text;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in YourDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                try
                {
                if (cell.Value != null && cell.Value.ToString() == searchValue)
                {
                    //cell.RowIndex;
                    YourDataGridView.CurrentCell = YourDataGridView.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Cells[0];//selects only a cell of the row in which the value was found, in this case cell with index 0
                    YourDataGridView.CurrentRow.Selected = true;//selects the whole row of the current selected cell
                }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No records found.");
                    //throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Introducing the power of LINQ

```
using System.Linq;

int GetRowID = YourDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Select(s => (s.Cells["YourColumnWhereToFind"].Value != null) ? 
            (s.Cells["YourColumnWhereToFind"].Value.ToString() == textBox1.Text) 
            ? s.Index : -1 : -1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Just handle if returned -1 because I think you will get index out of bounds. (?)